# Не правильно отображается состояние чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.

После добавления элементов при нажатии на кружок слева от введенного элемента не работает галочка чекбокса. И как сделать, чтобы в массив записывалось текущее состояние чекбокса, если выбран: "completed", то не выбран: "active". В массив записывается "completed", а при повторном нажатии на чекбокс не переписывает состояние в "active".

```js
var tasks = [];
var i = 0;

function updateTasks() {
  $('#todo-list').find('li').remove();
  $(tasks).each(function(i) {
    $('#todo-list').append('<li class="completed">\
            <div class="todo-task">\
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" data-id="' + i + '"><label class="text">' + tasks[i].title + '</label>\
            <button class="destroy" data-id="' + i + '"></button>\
            </div>\
            </li>');
  }); //Ошибка находиться где-то здесь, не знаю как исправить
  if (tasks.status === "completed") {
    $('#todo-list .toggle').prop('checked', true);
  } else if (tasks.status === "active") {
    $('#todo-list .toggle').prop('checked', false);
  }
  tasksCount();
}

function tasksCount() {
  $('.count').text(tasks.length);
  if (tasks.length < 1) {
    $('#footer').hide();
  }
}

/* Добавление задач */

$('#new-todo').keyup(function(event) {
  if ((event.keyCode === 13)) {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $('#main').show();
      $('#footer').show();
      var $this = $(this);
      var newTask = $this.val();
      tasks.push({
        id: i++,
        title: newTask,
        status: 'active'
      }); // Запись в массив здесь
      updateTasks();
      // Очистка Input
      $('#new-todo').val('');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

/* Checkbox */

$('#todo-list').on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
  tasks[id].status = "completed";
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) { //Кажется, что здесь неправильно написал изменения статуса в массиве
    tasks[id].status = "active";
  }
  updateTasks();
});


/* Удаление */

$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
  tasks.splice(id, 1);
  updateTasks();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#todo_app {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -155px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#new-todo {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.003);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)
}

input {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 90;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[placeholder] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#toggle-all {
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}

#toggle-all::before {
  content: "❯";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding: 10px 27px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
  background-color: initial;
  padding: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  font: 13px Arial;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

label[for='toggle-all'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

#todo-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#todo-list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#todo-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle:checked:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#todo-list li .toggle:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>')
}

#todo-list li.checked label {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#todo-list li label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
  display: block;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {}

#todo-list li .destroy {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #cc9a9a;
  margin: auto 0 11px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#todo-list li .destroy::after {
  content: "×";
}


/* Text footer */

#footer {
  color: #777777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6, 0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6, 0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.todo-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.todo-count strong {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#filters {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#filters li {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#filters li a.active {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:active {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:hover {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.1);
}

#filters li a {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#clear-completed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  margin: auto 0;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  line-height: 1;
}

footer a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section id="todo_app">
    <header>
      <input id="new-todo" autofocus>
    </header>
    <section id="main" style="display: none;">
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"> <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
      <ul id="todo-list">
        <!-- li class="completed">
        <div class="task">
          <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox"> </label>
          <button class="destroy"></button>
        </div>
      </li -->
      </ul>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer" style="display: none;">
      <span class="todo-count">
          <strong class="count"> </strong> items left
        </span>
      <ul id="filters">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-all-tasks">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-active-tasks">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-completed-tasks">Completed</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="clear-completed" style="display: none;">Clear completed</button>
    </footer>
  </section>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv2xL2c8/1/

Comment: слишком много кода и это не вопрос, а просьба сделать за Вас.

Comment: @OlmerDale если бы я хотел, чтобы за меня сделали, я бы так и написал. а я прошу мне подсказать как сделать.

Comment: @OlmerDale специально для вас оставил комментарии в том месте, где не работает, чтобы вам не пришлось вчитываться в код и искать

Comment: Комментарии - это хорошо, но [mcve] никто не отменял

Comment: Перед `if (tasks.status === "completed")` выведите `console.log(tasks);` и посмотрите, что у вас там лежит.

Comment: @YozhEzhi спасибо конечно, но проблему я уже давно решил.